# JavaScript/Swift + JavaScriptCore - Possible to ignore undefined variables?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I've got a web scraper-ish set of functions that I'm writing in Swift, and I'm using the JavaScriptCore library to... well, execute some JavaScript. I've scraped a file from the web, but it only has a couple of functions that I'm interested in. However, parts of the file contain things like `window` or `window.currentScript`, or `new window.WeakMap`... these things are unfortunately not defined in JavaScriptCore.

This is one of the errors that I'm getting, for example:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.document.currentScript.src.indexOf')`

Something I'm attempting to do in the meantime is monkeypatch all of the erroring things, like this:

`window={};window.document.currentScript.src={};window.document.currentScript.src.indexOf={}`

And prepending this to the JS. However, there must be a better way... right?

Comment: I had the idea of using a regex—maybe something like this? `(new|var|)\s*window.*?(?=\s|;|\)|]|&&|\|\||:|})` ... it's not perfect but it works (almost and usually)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was disregarding these references to `window` altogether—the functions I needed from the JS file didn't ever reference window or its properties. I did some regex magic (magix?) to extract the definitions of the functions I wanted, and made a new string for just those functions. Then, I gave that string to `JSContext.evaluateScript`. I hope this helps someone!